# some of methods in classes throughs error "not a member of org.deeplarning4j"

Tags: scala, deeplearning4j

I have been doing Deeplearning in Scala using Deeplearning4j framework , while building the model with predefined methods like learning rate, retrain , backdrop  throws me errors:

> not a member of org.deeplearning4j

I tried cleaning my SBT and creating new projects

```scala
val logisticRegressionConf : MultiLayerConfiguration = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
  .seed(123).learningRate(0.1).iterations(1).optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT).updater(new Nesterovs(0.9)) //High Level Configuration
  .list() //For configuring MultiLayerNetwork we call the list method
  .layer(0, outputLayer) //    <----- output layer fed here
  .pretrain(false).backprop(true) //Pretraining and Backprop Configuration
  .build() //Building Configuration
```

```
Error:(20, 20) value learningRate is not a member of org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder
.seed(123).learningRate(0.1).iterations(1).optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT).updater(new Nesterovs(0.9)) //High Level Configuration
```

Comment: What does your build.sbt look like?

Comment: link for the SBT:  https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-buildtools